# PHP CLI script keeps growing in memory while running

Tags: php, memory, out-of-memory

Hi I have a big script that runs on a Ubuntu box with PHP 5.6 .Basically it migrates tons of datas from an old DB to a new one.As I expected those kinds of problems i decided to use some ground rules from the start:

In the CLI php.ini memory limit set at -1.

When migrating a full table, rows are selected by chunk of 100 or 1000 rows depending on the column number so i doesn't run a huge select request returning potentially millions of rows.

All variables that i can pass via reference from a function to another are passed via reference.

All my code share the same organization.
The main function calls a function for each table i want to migrate.
They are almost the same, executing chunked select on the table and doing foreach on the result. 
Inside the foreach an other function is called with the row data as a referenced parameter. 
It's that final function that is going to migrate just 1 row and return the new id.

Only thing i keep in memory are arrays storing old_table_id to new_table_id from some tables. But it shouldn't exceed 50K records total ...

Anyway that script keep getting bigger and bigger  to the point it crashes because the box lacks memory (Ubuntu Vagrant box with 2GB Ram).

I don't know what to do next if someone has some experiences to share ...

Comment: it's hard to say without looking at the code. obviously there is some variable you are concatenating infinitively or may be an array you are adding items to.

Comment: Is it two different db-servers or just different databases on the same server?

Comment: the reason also may be that you don't release mysql resources after execution e.g. prepared statements.

Comment: We need to see your code, but try searching for variables you no longer need and unset them. Search for incrementally gathered data - it can be even somewhere inside your DB adapter (for some profiling purposes - memorizing each SQL that run since start etc.). Try to allocate problem using function memory_get_usage, debugger and - in the worst case scenario - using profiler.

Comment: @heximal : thanks for your advices. FYI code is right now > 2K code lines and idk if i can release it, i need to check. Concerning the sql query resources i need to check.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, two different servers.